# Export control rig from Maya to unreal engine

Tags: unreal, maya, rigging

I have a control rig in Maya and I want to import the same rig to Unreal for Keyframe animations. Is there a way to transfer the rig from Maya to Unreal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not an Unreal user myself, but [a tweet just crossed my feed](https://twitter.com/Skylonxe/status/1434277810001096712) about writing custom deformation logic into Unreal, which might be useful if the Maya rig includes any kinds of deformation that Unreal's skeletal animation system doesn't provide by default.

Comment: Thanks DMGregory I will check that.